# SharePoint list relationships and reports

Tags: list

I'm pretty new to SharePoint so please be kind.  What I'm trying to do seems fairly simple to me but I don't know how to implement in SharePoint.  I have multiple buildings in multiple states with multiple network devices inside them, i.e. switches connected to multiple computers.  I'd like to build some lists that relate these things so that i can show in some kind of report if switch X goes down all these computers are affected, or if building Y goes down these switches and these computers are affected.  Please see example below.

Michigan
  Building X
    Switch 1
      Computer 1
      Computer 2
    Switch 2
      Computer 3
      Computer 4
  Building Y
    Switch 3
      Computer 5
      Computer 6
  Building Z
    Switch 4
      Computer 7
      Computer 8

So if a State, building, or switch is marked as "down" everything below that item shows as down as well in some kind of easily read report.  Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Sharepoint 2013

Thanks,

Chuck

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating these 4 lists with columns in brackets.

1. State List (Title, Status)
2. Building List (Title, Status, State_Title_Lookup)
3. Switch List (Title, Status, Builing_Title_Lookup)
4. Computer List (Title, Status, Switch_Title_Lookup)

The Status is a choice column with values "Up" and "Down". "Up" being the default.

Now you have two options to implement the status change logic

1. Auto update status using workflows on first 3 lists. Example, if status is changed on State List, the workflow would update the status in Building list. Building list has its own workflow which would update the status in Switch list. Finally the workflow on Switch list would update the status on Computer list. If status is changed in Building list, update the status in Switch and Computer list.
2. Update status in all the lists manually.

For reporting, create another list with these lookup fields pointing to the above 4 lists.

1. State Status
2. Building Status
3. Switch Status
4. Computer Status

Once all done and working, you could use images for "Up" and "Down" using JSLink on the lists.

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction.  I have a couple questions though.  How can i make the "State_Status_Lookup" tied to the "State_Title_Lookup".  When I do the lookups it pulls them independently based on the column instead of tying them together.

Comment: @C.Meier. I have updated my answer. The State_Status_Lookup field is not required. The workflow on State list can find the related item in Building list using State_Title_Lookup field. Same for Building and Switch lists.